# Convert forEach List into json list in flutter

Tags: json, flutter

I am trying to get list of installed apps and able to get it using mentioned code. How to make this forEach information into Json list to save it to server  as json

```
  Future<void> getinstalledAppList() async{
    List<Application> apps = await DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications();

    apps.forEach((app) {
      var jsonList = app.appName;
      print(jsonList);
    });

  }
```

Output of print is like below :

```
I/flutter ( 5465): WooCommerce
I/flutter ( 5465): Amazon
I/flutter ( 5465): Weather
I/flutter ( 5465): OfficeSuite
```

I need output like:

```
{'WooCommerce', 'Amazon', 'Weather' , 'OfficeSuite'}
```

Comment: Application class is your won or belongs to any other package?

Comment: it belongs to other package named device apps

Comment: Can you update the question with expected json list?

Comment: Have edited question. I get list of names of apps, i need to make a list which I can save in backend.

Comment: it should be json array I think, you are posted object

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code which will extract appName from the application and make a list of it. You can directly write that list If you want JSON array in string format then you can make use of [jsonEncode()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html)

```
var appNamesList = apps.map((app)=>app.appName).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a global app name list. And push items into this list. After that, you can easily send it to the server. It will look like this:

```
  List<String> appNameList = List<String>();

  Future<void> getinstalledAppList() async {
    List<Application> apps = await DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications();

    apps.forEach((app) {
      var jsonList = app.appName;

      appNameList.add(app.appName); // Here we add them to a string list.
      print(jsonList);
    });
  }


  Future<void> callThisFunction(List<String> appNameList) async {
    // Here we can send the list to server
    await saveAppNameListToServer(appNameList);
  }
```